# overriding property attribute in class extension

Tags: objective-c

Say I have an interface

```
// Car.h
@interface Car 
@property ( readonly) NSInteger rpm
@end
```

I want all the users of this to access this as readonly

In other areas that are private to my code and not exposed to users I want to manipulate the rpm

Say

```
// EngineFeedback.h
@interface EngineFeedback
@property(nonatomic , weak ) Car *theCar;
@end

// EngineFeedback.m 
-(void) engineRPMReceived:(NSInteger) newRPM
{
     theCar.rpm = newRPM;
}
```

How can I accomplish this (where I need this to be writeable)

Can I define a class Extension that overrides the attributes

```
// Car_Internal.h
@interface Car ()
@property(readwrite) NSInteger rpm 
@end
```

To be able to use this as

```
    // EngineFeedback.m 
    #import "Car_Internal.h"
    -(void) engineRPMReceived:(NSInteger) newRPM
    {
         theCar.rpm = newRPM;
    }
```

Is this bad ? Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a class extension to override a `readonly` property declaration is perfectly fine. (In fact that's the primary purpose of the `readonly` attribute.) However, your `Car` class would need to provide an implementation of `setRpm:` for this to work at runtime.

So given the declarations you provided, somewhere in `Car.m` you'd need something like this:

```
- (void)setRpm:(NSInteger)newRPM
{
     _rpm = newRPM;
}
```

Note that the class extension can be declared in `EngineFeedback.m` if you prefer.

Comment: @Maverick447 Makes sense. I'll update my answer. By the way, a more technically correct way to phrase your comment would be "Instances of the EngineFeedback class manage an instance of the Car class," or, "An EngineFeedback object manages an instance of Car."